# Filtering list items with case insensitive

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Need help to minimize the code.I have used RegEx to filter data from a JSON file to accept (I)teration as well (i)teration. But while replacing the list items which has Iteration or iteration, I can only replace one. by appending the results I am getting the desired output, but it stretches the code for this simple task.and I am not sure though tomorrow I may get Iteration as iTERaTion ..

My goal is to extract the only numbers from the list items to convert it to date time format, which I will be taking care.

Code:

```
print("Unfiltered Folders : \n", Path_List)
regex = re.compile('(?i)^20\d{6}-Iteration$')
regex1 = re.compile('(?i)-iteration$')
Filtered_Path_List = list(filter(regex.search,Path_List))
print("List of Iteration folder will be considered for further Process: \n", 
Filtered_Path_List)

final_iteration = [e.replace("-Iteration", "") for e in Filtered_Path_List]     
print("Latest Iteration list : ", final_iteration)
```

LOG:

```
    Unfiltered Folders : 
 ['20171226-Iteration', '20180105-iteration', '20180112-iteration', '20180117-Iteration', '20180118-Iteration', '20180123-Iteration', '20180124-Iteration', '20180202-Iteration', '20180207-Iteration', '20180220-Iteration', '20180321-Iteration', '20180322-Iteration', '20180327-Iteration', '_Kyle-AutomationTesting', '_Template']
List of Iteration folder will be considered for further Process: 
 ['20171226-Iteration', '20180105-iteration', '20180112-iteration', '20180117-Iteration', '20180118-Iteration', '20180123-Iteration', '20180124-Iteration', '20180202-Iteration', '20180207-Iteration', '20180220-Iteration', '20180321-Iteration', '20180322-Iteration', '20180327-Iteration']
Latest Iteration list :  ['20171226', '20180105-iteration', '20180112-iteration', '20180117', '20180118', '20180123', '20180124', '20180202', '20180207', '20180220', '20180321', '20180322', '20180327']
all_iteration.txt file created on : 2018-04-12 16:44

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see the final_iteration[] has '20180105-iteration', '20180112-iteration' without filter effect.

Comment: I do not really get your point. Do you want to just to perform a regex with case insensitivity? You can that setting the flag `re.I` (as long as I remember)

Comment: Does it help while iterating through list items.Would like to replace the items which has -Iteration in it regardless of its case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this code what I changed for applying case-insensitive.

```
final_iteration = [re.sub("(?i)-Iteration", "",e) for e in Filtered_Path_List]
```

in which I used `re.sub()` instead of `e.replace()` in your script.

Then `iteration`s are all removed in the output as follows

```
Latest Iteration list :  ['20171226', '20180105', '20180112', '20180117', '20180118', '20180123', '20180124', '20180202', '20180207', '20180220', '20180321', '20180322', '20180327']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.compile('^20\d{6}(?=-iteration$)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Not only will this do the regex case insensitive, it'll also, select only the date portion from the string